# My Game Renders Awful In Android Build

Tags: android, rendering, unity

I'm working on a 3D Sniper game and have finished the project. When I test it on Windows (7). It's All Fine, not even a bug. But when I take the app into android (Bluestacks App Player), my buttons and images render in Solid Black color. and my trees are Solid White. Some materials are rendering black too. You can see this in the image below

[image]

That Black Square On Top Right Corner Is A UI Button And The White Regions Are Tree And Bushes. The Black Thing In The Bottom Is A APC Tank.

Comment: What are you using, uGui or NGUI?

Comment: For GUI Elements I Use Standart Unity GUI Elements. Did you mean that?

Comment: double check the sprite property. Verify if normal texture have `Texture Type` to `Texture` not `Sprite`

Comment: For My buttons i use sprites. but for raw images i use textures. what is the problem with my trees? where did it cae=me from?

Comment: what shaders are you using?

Comment: the trees do not have any shader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33153/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-hossein-maktoobian).